# How to fix Ubuntu 17.10 BIOS corruption, after uninstalling Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, 17.10, bios

I have a Lenovo Y50-70 and apparently I am suffering from this issue https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1734147

The problem is I have recently removed Ubuntu by deleting it's partition using Disk Manager in Windows 10, so I am unable to follow the steps described in the above link, since I don't have Ubuntu anymore.

So I am now stuck with a read-only BIOS and can't even boot from USB.

Is there a way to fix the BIOS corruption from Windows 10 ?

Comment: My guess is you can try some of these: https://windowsreport.com/bios-corruption-windows-10/  Or you can try reflashing your BIOS from Windows:  https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/lenovo-y-series-laptops/y50-70-notebook-lenovo/downloads/ds100998

Comment: I have tried that, unfortunately I can't flash the BIOS because the utility detects I have the latest version already. Clearing CMOS didn't help either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you can boot into Windows 10, here's the procedure for the fix:

1. Download the latest Ubuntu [17.10-series release from Canonical](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/contribute/?version=17.10.1&architecture=amd64). Their build has the fix for the Intel SPI issue above.
2. Create a bootable USB from your Windows OS. You can use a tool such as [etcher.io](https://etcher.io/) due to its' simplicity and speed.
3. With the now bootable USB drive still plugged in, hold down the Shift key and reboot your laptop from the Windows shutdown menu. This will take you to the recovery menu where you can select the option to boot up from a device. Select it and you should be able to boot up the Ubuntu 17.10 bootable USB.
4. Once it  boots up, simply shut down or restart the machine from the live environment and confirm that the BIOS issue is fixed.

Report back with your findings.

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked! I should have thought of that.

Answer (score 0):

I have done exactly the same thing on my Lenevo ideapad but my one saving grace is that when I boot up I can gain access to Windows 10 by pressing F12. Hope this is of some small help.