# Ubuntu 17.10 corrupted bios Lenovo with USB boot device

Tags: lenovo, bios, bug-reporting

I've a problem, related to [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1734147).

I've booted Ubuntu 17.10 from a USB stick on mine Lenovo G-50 (I don't remember now if in Live or persistence mode), after that moment I coulnd't change BIOS settings anymore, now every time I power on my laptop a message appears saying:

```
EFI USB boot failed
```

And I need to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to enter in Windows 8.1 (which is on my hard drive) , if I change the settings in the BIOS they won't be saved, does the workaround of changing kernel of Ubuntu works for me too?

What should I do? Create a USB boot device with Ubuntu 17.10 and follow the instructions to change the kernel?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The bug is fixed in the 'artful dot one' release 17.10.1, that you find at http://releases.ubuntu.com/17.10.1/

[Ubuntu 17.10.1 ISOs Now Available To Avoid Thrashing Some UEFI Systems](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Ubuntu-17.10.1-Released)

> It was a [BIOS/UEFI corrupting problem](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Ubuntu-17.10-BIOS-Corrupter) but fortunately for
>   affected users [a software fix was discovered](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Ubuntu-17.10-Laptop-Fix) to make the hardware
>   happy again.
>
> It's important to note that this 17.10.1 ISO re-release does not have
>   any KPTI/Retpoline for Meltdown/Spectre mitigation or other changes.
>   So it's still important to update your system once installed.

Comment: So should i create another usb boot device with that version, boot from it in live mode and i can change the bios settings again? Sorry, noob here

Comment: Yes, that is a good idea.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, however I didn't succed to boot from usb where was installed with Rufus the Ubuntu 17.10.1 version's  using filesystem  fat32 and GPT partition for UEFI as settings. Mine pendrive just won't show up in the boot options. I'll probably look for an update of the bios.

Comment: @Stefano, 1. Please check the md5sum, that the iso file is good; 2. Try to **clone** from the iso file to the USB pendrive with [Win32 Disk Imager](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Win32DiskImager/iso2usb) in Windows or the Startup Disk Creator, Disks or [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) in Ubuntu. A cloned Ubuntu 64-bit system in a pendrive can boot both in UEFI mode and BIOS (CSM, legacy) mode. -- But the computer must be able to boot from USB, maybe you are right: that is the problem.

Comment: Another idea: Are you able to unplug the internal drive? In that case (when no internal drive is found) I think the computer might be more willing to boot from USB.

Comment: @Stefano, Maybe the following link can help you, [How to fix Ubuntu 17.10 BIOS corruption, after uninstalling Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/997363/how-to-fix-ubuntu-17-10-bios-corruption-after-uninstalling-ubuntu?rq=1)

Comment: I've already seen it but dosen't work, in the recovery menu mine pendrive isn't listed, there are other people's comments [link](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1734147) which weren't able to boot from pendrive/cd rom, the only workaround seems to create a second partition on the hd with ubuntu (never done it before and not sure if it will work at 100%)

Comment: If you can unplug the internal drive there are actually two options: 1. as I described before (the computer might boot from USB); 2. You can connect the drive to another computer and install Ubuntu into it. Normally PC computers are similar enough for an installed system to be portable. But before doing that you should **backup** your Windows and above all your personal files, that you cannot afford to lose.

Comment: On my Lenovo Fn-F2 gets you to BIOS, and (probably what you need) Fn-F12 adds usb as a boot option.

Hope it helps.
BTW I also have a corrupted BIOS.

Comment: how did you resolved it? however mine pendrive isn't found  and bios settings  won't  save..

Comment: @Stefano, **1.** Please tell us, if you can boot your Lenovo G-50 into any operating system (for example from the internal drive), and in that case into what operating system; **2.** Are you able to unplug the internal drive? In that case (when no internal drive is found) I think the computer might be more willing to boot from USB. Please try that if possible. -- When we know your results, we can go ahead an look for possible ways to solve your problems.

Comment: @Stefano, There are posts in the following thread indicating success, if the computer can boot into Windows or Ubuntu from the internal drive. It seems a post of yours is merged by a moderator into this thread, but maybe you have not yet tried according to this thread. There are also hardware methods, that should be done by an experienced hardware technician at a computer shop (which would be the last alternative). See [this link (and scroll to read all the answers)](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Linux-Discussion/Ubuntu-17-10-corrupts-Lenovo-BIOS-USB-not-recognized-not-saving/td-p/3887679)

Comment: @sudodus Sorry if i replay after a week, but it is not mine laptop and can't have a daily access to it. However in mine bios settings i have  boot mode on : UEFI, USB boot: enabled, fast boot: enabled, PXE boot to lan: enabled. Then on EFI order: EFI usb device,Windows boot manager,EFI network,EFI cd. I can boot into windows 8.1 after the error message when i power on. I've  followed this guide to create a usb uefi bootable device : https://www.lifewire.com/create-uefi-bootable-ubuntu-usb-drive-2202085, but when i select usb on boot option: "UEFI boot device failed "appear

Comment: 1. Try to disable fast boot; 2. Does the USB drive (as it is *now*) work (to boot from) in another computer? 3. Are you able to unplug the internal drive? In that case (when no internal drive is found) I think the computer might be more willing to boot from USB. Please try that if possible.

Comment: Etcher has a good reputation. That lifewire link should be OK. (Rufus is another tool, that works well in Windows.)