# Fixing a broken bios lenovo

Tags: uefi, lenovo

I am a little bit stuck. Since I've installed Ubuntu 17.10 on my laptop. 
It corrupted my bios from my laptop (I have a Lenovo Y50).

This means that I cannot

- Change my bios
- Boot using USB
- And EFI entries read-only

So I installed Windows using another laptop and put the disk in the laptop. So I can work with it. The problem now is that there is a fix for the bios (using Ubuntu). But I can't boot Ubuntu from USB or hard disk.

When I use the same way to install Ubuntu on a hard disk and connect it to the laptop, it won't boot at all.

Is there a way to fix this :)

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1734147

Comment: According to this thread a fix is possible https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013832/ubuntu-17-10-corrupted-bios-lenovo-with-usb-boot-device.

Answer (score 2):

If you are able to boot in Windows the BIOS can be re-flashed with the [Y50-70 Laptop BIOS Update](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/lenovo-y-series-laptops/y50-70-notebook-lenovo/downloads/ds100998) If you are not able to boot then you will not be able to run the BIOS update. You will have to send the laptop to Lenovo to re-flash the BIOS.

A clip From [Phoronix - Ubuntu 17.10 Temporarily Pulled Due To A BIOS Corrupting Problem:](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Ubuntu-17.10-BIOS-Corrupter)

Should your BIOS be corrupted, you may need to replace your motherboard if there is not a removable flash chip. There are some reports that resetting the BIOS does work, but it's too early to know if that works for everyone. This issue has been confirmed for several different lines of Lenovo laptops including the Yoga and IdeaPad products. There is also the reports of it affecting a few Acer, Toshiba and Dell laptops.

When the BIOS is corrupted by the Intel SPI kernel driver, the effects range from being unable to save BIOS settings to no longer being able to boot from USB devices.

The Intel SPI kernel driver is responsible for reading/writing to SPI serial flash. Due to the SPI serial flash holding the BIOS and other platform specific data, Intel's driver is supposed to make the contents read-only, but clearly something is going awry with the driver in 17.10.

Comment: first of all thank you for your answer.  the problem is if I cannot boot Ubuntu format hard disk.  yesterday I connect a a hard drive with Ubuntu on it. Internal harddrive, Didn't load. I have the same issue with one USB stick I have only the possibility to boot something using a pxe server.

Comment: The second problem that I have is that I cannot flash  my bios  using Windows. If you download program to Flash your laptop  it does not work. It will reboot your computer and nothing is changed

Comment: I would send a email to Lenovo tech support.

Comment: Please report back any findings.  The same happened with me.  I have a Lenovo B50-80.

Comment: @stumblebee I've already asked this on the Lenovo forum. But I get less information than on 'askubuntu'.

Answer (score 1):

Sup Guys (and girls),

One of my friends connected a usb 2.0 on it (UEFI) (on a usb 2.0 port).
This with a disconnected HDD. So It loaded (took us one hour to find out).
After that we installed Ubuntu and installed the patch. So my laptop is working again.

(after the install, I downloaded http://people.canonical.com/~ypwong/lp1734147/linux-image-4.15.0-041500rc6-generic_4.15.0-041500rc6.201712312330+20170103+1_amd64.deb package and installed it)